# How to create a SQL database in Windows Azure and tables in that data base?

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5

How to create a SQL database in Windows Azure and tables ? 
What is the difference between SQL database and Data Storage in Windows Azure?
How to connect the SQL database tables in MVC5 application?

Answer (score 1):

In short it can be done from Visual Studio. There are free Community RC edition, 2015. A model created in C# (Code First Entity Framework). Then it is published through a wizard to Azure.

Azure Table Storage is used for non relational data kept in tables. It allows basic queries. Also there are in Azure Storage a Queue and Blob. For messages and for big data like videos.

Here is a starting guide for all of this at http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application . Also there're a lot of starter and useful info.